# How to write a formula using sql recursion

Tags: sql

using SQL recursion, I am trying to get a formula from a given set of numbers.

Example, if only 1 number x is provided, the output should be x.

if 2 numbers x and y are provided, then output should be x + y + xy

if 3 numbers are provide, output should be x + y + z + xy + yz + zx + xyz

excerpt:

thanks.
Priya

Comment: Why do you use SQL for this???

Comment: Provided? Provided in a table? As input to a proc? Is there a table involved here? This isn't clear at all. If this is homework (it smells like homework) please share your attempt at solving it. It will do you know good if we just come up with the answer for you to copy and paste and, honestly, it's not that rewarding for us either.

Comment: I see no recursion formula, how res(i) = f(res(i-1), i).

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please. Otherwise this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want the result set to really look like.  But, you can do this using a recursive CTE:

```
with vals as (
      select *
      from (values ('x'), ('y'), ('z')) v(a)
     ),
     cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), a) as a, convert(varchar(max), a) as max_a
      from vals
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), cte.a + vals.a) as a, convert(varchar(max), vals.a)
      from cte join
           vals
           on vals.a > cte.max_a
     )
select cte.a
from cte;
```

This produces the expressions on each row